# How to find sum of a group of items' values based on the last value of each item?

Tags: filter, excel-formula, group-by, sum, excel-2021

In Excel, I have a table of historical value data of different items in multiple groups of items. As a new item's record entered, the old value of that item has to be abandoned and the total values of items in the group must be recalculated based on the new item's value. In each group, based on group name and date specified, just the last record of each item is embraced; every item has different last date less than the date specified. I want to find the sum  of items' values in each group based on group name and specific date, how do i do this?

[image: image of the sample table(input and desired output)]

As displayed in the image, data are grouped in two groups, G1 and G2,... In each row I need to calculate the total value of items in its corresponding group that already been entered until that date. At the right of the table, I filtered the desired records based on the Date and Group fields, then the output will be the sum of the Values displayed in green frame.
In date D3, as a new value entered for Item i11, the group total value recalculated based on this new value. Also in the table, the total value of each group in each row is displayed in column [Sum of Group], also by formula in the last two columns.

Data:

| Row | Group | Item | Date | Value | Sum of Group *(expected output)* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | G1 | i11 | D1 | 10 | 30 |
| 2 | G1 | i12 | D1 | 20 | 30 |
| 3 | G1 | i13 | D2 | 30 | 60 |
| 4 | G1 | i11 | D3 | 40 | 90 |
| 5 | G1 | i14 | D4 | 50 | 140 |
| 6 | G1 | i13 | D5 | 60 | 170 |
| 7 | G1 | i13 | D6 | 70 | 190 |
| 8 | G1 | i13 | D6 | 80 | 190 |
| 9 | G1 | i12 | D7 | 90 | 260 |
| 10 | G1 | i14 | D8 | 100 | 310 |
| 11 | G2 | i21 | D8 | 110 | 110 |
| 12 | G1 | i13 | D9 | 120 | 350 |
| 13 | G2 | i22 | D9 | 130 | 270 |
| 14 | G2 | i21 | D9 | 140 | 270 |

Comment: Please add sample data (including both input and desired output) in markdown form: I recommend https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged Excel 2010.

I managed to get a solution in Office 365:

```
=LET(f,FILTER(HSTACK([Item],ROW([Item])-1),([Group]=[@Group])*([Date]<=[@Date])),
     i,TAKE(f,,1),
     r,DROP(f,,1),
SUM(INDEX([Value],FILTER(r,MMULT((TOROW(i)=i)*(TOROW(r)>=r),SEQUENCE(ROWS(f))^0)=1))))
```

[image]

The formula first filters all items `i` of the same group and same date or smaller - together with it's row references (minus 1), since the table starts at row 2,which is the first row, so `ROW(2)-1` = 1) `r`.

MMULT is used to check if there are any duplicate items within the filter result. Only the last found item of `i` is returned as TRUE.

This is used as a FILTER condition, to remove previous duplicates and only return the row numbers of the last found values of `i`.

These row numbers are used on the INDEXed `Item` column and these returned values are SUMmed.

---

or when you're on Beta Chanel Insiders:

`=LET(f,FILTER(HSTACK(Table2[Item],ROW(Table2[Item])),(Table2[Group]=Table2[@Group])*(Table2[Date]<=Table2[@Date])),SUM(INDEX(E:E,DROP(GROUPBY(TAKE(f,,1),DROP(f,,1),MAX,,0),,1))))`

Comment: Thank you. I could verify the algorithm, but as I work with Excel-2021, I can't test it.

Comment: I think this is compatible:
`=LET(f,FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},[Item],ROW([Item])-1),([Group]=[@Group])*([Date]<=[@Date])),i,INDEX(f,,1),r,INDEX(f,,2),SUM(INDEX([Value],FILTER(r,MMULT((TOROW(i)=i)*(TOROW(r)>=r),SEQUENCE(ROWS(f))^0)=1))))`

Comment: TOROW is an Office 365 function, how could its function be implemented in Excel 2021?

Comment: Oh, my bad, replace it with TRANSPOSE `=LET(f,FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2},[Item],ROW([Item])-1),([Group]=[@Group])*([Date]<=[@Date])),i,INDEX(f,,1),r,INDEX(f,,2),SUM(INDEX([Value],FILTER(r,MMULT((TRANSPOSE(i)=i)*(TRANSPOSE(r)>=r),SEQUENCE(ROWS(f))^0)=1))))`

Comment: This is correct and excellent. It will be perfect, if please explain how it works, or give some references on the subject. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think I already explained the logic, maybe I didn't explain MMULT in detail here. Maybe this is helpful: https://superuser.com/a/1814816/1856315

Answer (score 0):

This formula spills the results in my sheet.

EDIT: Changed SEQUENCE(14) to SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)) in order to dynamically return the number of rows in a sequence. The screenshot still shows the old version SEQUENCE(14).

=LET(data,A2:E15,DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,
LET(
z,FILTER(HSTACK(CHOOSECOLS(data,1),CHOOSECOLS(data,3)),(CHOOSECOLS(data,2)=INDEX(CHOOSECOLS(data,2),y))*(CHOOSECOLS(data,4)<=INDEX(CHOOSECOLS(data,4),y))),
u,SORTBY(z,DROP(z,,1),-1,TAKE(z,,1),-1),
v,XLOOKUP(UNIQUE(DROP(u,,1)),DROP(u,,1),TAKE(u,,1)),
SUM(INDEX(CHOOSECOLS(data,5),v))))))
,1)
)

[image: How to find sum of a group of items' values based on the last value of each item?]